# Can I embed the Active into My Tomcat?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, tomcat

i need to Integrate tomcat with active MQ for Messaging service  can i embed the 
   activeMQ in tomcat with out no separate installation of active mq on separate system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can take a look at this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/tomcat.html) of activemq documentation for details.